# MultiBinding with MultiValueConverter does not update

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

it seems that I have a problem with my multibinding.

Scenario:
I have a window with two datepickers and a listview.
The listliew contains some data bound elements called "entries". An entry has a property called "date".

I just want my listview to show entries whose date is in between my two datepickes dates.

My xaml code for binding the listview to the entries and dates:

```
<ListView.ItemsSource>
  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EntriesFilterConv}"
                UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
    <Binding Path="Entries" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
    <Binding ElementName="EntryFromDate" Path="SelectedDate"
             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
    <Binding ElementName="EntryToDate" Path="SelectedDate"
             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
  </MultiBinding>
</ListView.ItemsSource>
```

However, this doesnt work. My converter is called when a SelectedDate changes but its never called when Entries changes.

With normal data binding like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}">
  ...
</ListView>
```

The listview updates normally.
Any idea?

Comment: I would remove all the UpdateSourceTriggers, they should be redundant because the `ListView` will not modify those properties, hence the sources will never be updated anyway.

Comment: Thanks, but this did not help.

Comment: I know, that is why i posted it as a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the following might cause this: If you bind directly to the `Entries` the ListView will listen to `CollectionChanged` events, but if such a binding is inside a `MultiBinding` the only thing that would cause a reevaluation could be a `PropertyChanged` notification, which might not exist for the Entries property in your model.

Maybe you can subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event of your collection and raise a `PropertyChanged` event or get the `BindingExpression` within your `MultiBinding` to call an update manually.

Comment: I will try so. But what property should I use? Is there a property called `this`?

Comment: What does your model look like? Where is `Entries` defined? Also take a look at the INotifyPropertyChanged documentation if you are not familiar with that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx

Comment: I have a generic class `ViewModelCollection<T>`which inherits from `IList<T>`, `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`. In this case `Entries`is a `ViewModelCollection<EntryViewModel>`. Can I subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` within my class?

Comment: Oh, maybe you could try raising PropertyChanged with `Binding.IndexerName` then.

Answer (score 13):

After searching for hours, I find a simple and decent answer !
Since ObservableCollection doesn't raise PropertyChanged event but CollectionChanged, we just have to bind the collection's Count to fire the event when the list changes :

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{Resources:ListToStringConverter}">
    <Binding Path="List.Count" />
    <Binding Path="List" />
</MultiBinding>
```

Original infos about this perfectly working multibinding here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10884002/817504

Comment: That is not recommended because it may cause a memory leak as you can see here:

[Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/938416).

It happens because that property is not a dependency property and doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged, so the only way WPF has to "bind" to that property is using PropertyDescriptor, that attaches a PropertyChanged event causing a hard reference to that property.

Comment: If you have your property in a viewmodel, you can raise the property changed event manually when the collection changes (in the setter, for example).