# Converter not called when Object property inside List in Listview changes

Tags: wpf, listview, binding, converters, observablecollection

```
TemplateSwitcher
                 ShowAlternativeTemplate="{Binding Options, Converter={StaticResource ListToVisibilityConverter}}">
                TemplateSwitcher.AlternativeTemplate starts
                            shows a watermark  // Line A
                TemplateSwitcher.AlternativeTemplate ends
                // actual template which shows up if alternative template is not the case
                ScrollViewer
                    ListView
                        // SHows a list of options and with each option , there are two buttons - Accept option/ Reject option
                        /* Clicking on Accept sets the isOptionAccepted to true; */
                    ListView ends
                ScrollViewer ends
Tempalte switcherends
```

- *Options* = ObservableCollection of ***EachOption*** type; ***EachOption*** has a bool? field called 
  *isOptionAccepted*

What I am trying to achieve is:

- When the page loads: If the *Options* field is null/Empty : Shows
  alternative template(watermark) as in Line A in XAML     // Happens correctly
- When the user clicks on Accept
  option:      The list in the UI should NOT show this option. However,
  other options in the ObservableCollection still appear.// I have acheived this by binding the visibility of each listviewitem to the *isOptionAccepted* field

Now, when **all** the options are accepted, it would mean that no options should  show up in the UI,which is happening correctly. However, as a result I want it to show the alternative template(watermark) in Line A of XAML. I am unable to implement this.

Took a look at the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816163/when-will-the-valueconverters-convert-method-be-called-in-wpf) example but I am still not able to solve this. With this converter, the options do not show up in the List at all. I have set a breakpoint inside the converter and I was expecting to hit the breakpoint whenever I click on Accept (because that is modifying a property of the object ***EachOption***)
 Any help is appreciated.

Below is the ListToVisibilityConverter

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return true;
        else
        {
            ObservableCollection<EachOption> optionList= value as ObservableCollection;
            if (optionList != null)
            {
                foreach (EachOption eachOpt in optionList)
                {
                    if (eachOpt.isOptionAccepted!= true)
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: given these information I can only guess. ` the options do not show up in the List at all` so I think there is something wrong with the way u are initiating or changing the list. if it's and observable collection, then it must be initiated only once and if you want to change it you must only add/remove to/from it.

Comment: I understand the reason why it does not show up options in the list. It is because of the line if (eachOpt.isOptionAccepted!= true)
                        return true;

Comment: Initially, all *EachOption*'s have isOptionAccepted is set to false. So, even if I change that, I don't see that I am hitting a breakpoint inside the converter if I click on *Accept option*.

Comment: you said the breakpoint is not hitting. so it can't be because of that line. correct?

Comment: sorry I think i misunderstood the question. I think what you are looking for is `TemplateSelector`

Comment: I think it would be easier to implement if I can figure out a way to invoke my converter when the list element(in this case - an object) is modified. Or another option would be to explicitly raise property changed on the list element(in this case - an object)

Comment: You can manually implement that however you should ask another question with the related code you have tried, also I suggest trying template selector first as it does exactly what you need.